# A question on differentiable map

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to R$ be a differentiable map  Define $F=\{f'(t);a<t<b\}$ and $E=\{\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}:a<x<y<b\}$. Which of the following statements is true?

(a) $\bar{F}\subseteq \bar{E}$

(b)$\bar{E}= \bar{F}$

(c)$\bar{E}\subseteq \bar{F}$

(d) $E=F$

Comment: I think you did a typing mistake in (b) and (c)

Comment: Use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Hints: $E\subseteq F$ by the Mean Value Theorem. $F\subseteq\overline E$ by the definition of derivative. $E\ne F$ (consider the function $f(x)=x^3$).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you